# Populate and check for numeric-only textbox

Tags: javascript

I have two text boxes, I need to populate value of one text box to another textbox and value entered in textbox should be numeric only.

```
/* for numeric value in one textbox and populate in another*/

function onType(evt){
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){ 
return false;
}
else{
document.getElementById("marketValuationId").value=document.getElementById("valuationId").value;
return true;
}
```

Comment: so what is the exact problem that is happening.. and this onType() is attached to which text box?

Comment: `event` should likely also be `evt`

Comment: i have two text boxes i need to populate value of one text box to another textbox and value entered in textbox should be numeric only but in my code textbox is accepting chacters also which i dont want i want only numbers in textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
function onType(evt) {
  var charCode = event ? event.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode < 48 && charCode > 57) {
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("marketValuationId").value = document.getElementById("valuationId").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var copyText = function (x, y) {
        if (!isNaN(Number(x.value))) {
            document.getElementById(y).value = x.value;
        }
    };
```

variable x should be the `this` keyword where this keyword as this function is attached to a given DOM node and variable y should be the id attribute value of the element to write to.

Example:

```
<input id="input" onkeyup="copyText(this, 'output')" type="text"/>
<input id="output" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in my code and now this is working fine!

```
function isNumericKey(e)
{
    if (window.event) { var charCode = window.event.keyCode; }
    else if (e) { var charCode = e.which; }
    else { return true; }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) { return false; }
    document.getElementById('marketValuationId').value=document.getElementById('valuationId').value;
    return true;
}
```